# Flag dialog pages should include "other" reference

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

With all due respect to the flag dialog designers, many of the sets of choices leave me wanting to say "none of the above". One of the most frustrating occurred recently about four pages "in" when I was left with a set of alternative SE sites on which this question belonged. Since the question was a dup of a question on Programmers, I was disappointed and surprised not to see Programmers listed.

I see from other meta questions that the decision to restrict the choices is conscious in many cases and the recommended workaround is usually to just "leave it to the moderator", which I assume refers to selecting the "needs attention / other" option at the top level of the dialog.  If that's the case, then how about including a reference to that option on each page if not a link to that point in the dialog?

Update: As was pointed out in the answer below, there already is a link to the top level of the dialog in the "path links" at the top of the page, so "getting back" is not particularly difficult. My main reason for suggesting this, however, is to convey to the user that: a) the set of choices at any particular dialog point is known not to be comprehensive, b) there is in fact a "leave it to the moderator" options, and c) it's "ok" to invoke that option if none of the choices seem to match. Note also that if a "none of the above" link is provided on each page, it can be readily used to collect data on which pages are problematic.

Comment: Is it really *that* much of a bother to click the one link to go back to the top level of the flag dialog to then select "other"?  You're cluttering up every single other page to also include it on every sub-menu when it's only a single click away.

Comment: It's not an ease-of-use thing from my point of view, but rather an acknowledgement that the choices aren't comprehensive and it's ok for the user to fall back to the generic "needs addition / other" category rather than just give up out of frustration with the design, which I think is a fairly natural reaction.

Comment: `Since the question was a dup of a question on Programmers, I was disappointed and surprised not to see Programmers listed` <-- So your beef is with the list of migration choices? That's a different animal...

Comment: @voretaq7 - I used the case of Programmers not being listed along with the meta answers which said that the list of alternative sites was intentionally limited as an *example* of the general phenomenon which I think exists of the dialog choices not being comprehensive.

Answer (score 5):

The breadcrumbs at the top of the flagging dialog are links back through the path you took to get to the current page you're on.

[image: Flagging Dialog Breadcrumbs]

Just click on the first one to get back to the main page with a generic **it needs ♦ moderator attention** option.

Comment: The screenshot is just taunting the OP with your "belongs on another site in the SE network" search box.

Comment: @Servy Whoops! Err... Pay no attention to that text box at the bottom of the dialog. That doesn't do anything!

Comment: Pay no attention to the Bill behind the Lizard?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin The unrestricted "Belongs on <insert any site you want here>" line is a moderator-only feature ([tag:status-bydesign] - that's how the the "Leave it to the moderators" bit works). You could have 999,999 rep and it still wouldn't be available unless you had a diamond :) (A good case for showing it to a user with a high *network total* reputation and a good proportion of "off-site" rep could probably be made though...)

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm completely fine with "leaving it the moderator", in fact I appreciate that service. My issue is that the current design may lead people to feel that their only options are selecting a choice that isn't right or "giving up". I've used this SE list as an example, but most of the flag dialog pages leave me with the same feeling due to either to limited choices or inconsistent/ambiguous wording of the descriptions. My suggestion is not about number of mouse clicks, it's about communicating to the user that in all cases they have the "let the moderator deal with it" option.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin This isn't an example of a "let them eat cake" mentality. I'm telling you to click on the link at the top of the dialog, which you do have access to, not to use the text box at the bottom, which you don't.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Acknowledged. Bad analogy on my part. Sorry about that. I deleted the comment and thanks for being one of those who has to deal with the "other" situations.